# getting unique values grouped by date in solr

Tags: solr, facet

I have been struggling over a week to write a query in solr, which must return the UNIQUE value of the column actorPreferredUsernam group by postedTime.

The equivalent SQL logic is as follows

```sql
select count(distinct actorPreferredUsernam),postedTime from tweets 
group by postedTime
```

I am using the new release of solr 5.1.

Comment: the best query i come up with is  
json.facet={postedTime:%27unique(actorPreferredUsername)%27}
&facet.range=postedTime
&facet.range.start=2014-12-02T21:05:35Z&fl=postedTime
&unique(actorPreferredUsername)&facet=true
&f.postedTime.facet.range.end=2014-12-02T21:05:35Z
&f.postedTime.facet.range.gap=+1DAY
&facet.field=postedTime

Answer (score 0):

There are not so many details in the question.
For example, is the postedTime a date field ?
With which precision ? day ? hour ? ms ?
in the case I find quit useless to group by dates, as we will have completely distincts groups ( depending on the precision of the date) .

Assuming we can group properly, probably I would suggest you Pivot faceting :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Pivot(DecisionTree)Faceting

Hope this helps.